# How do I save an imported file name as string after importing file in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui

I am trying import a JSON file onto my app and I trying to read the name so that I can use that string to display the JSON onto my app. I have the file importer working but I need help on saving that name of the file as a String.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var imported = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Button(action: {imported.toggle()}, label: {
                Text("Import")
            })
        }
        
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $imported, allowedContentTypes: [.json]) { (res) in

        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. What have you tried? What kind of storage have you researched? SO isn’t a code writing service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var imported = false
    @State var fileName = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 30) {
            Button(action: {imported.toggle()}, label: {
                Text("Import")
            })
            Text("file selected is \(fileName)")  // <--- the file name you selected
        }
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $imported, allowedContentTypes: [.json]) { res in
            do {
                let fileUrl = try res.get()
                self.fileName = fileUrl.lastPathComponent  // <--- the file name you want

                let fileData = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
                // try! JSONDecoder().decode([YourObject].self, from: fileData)

            } catch{
                print ("error reading: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does this save the json onto the app too or is there a different logic for that?

Comment: I don't understand the question here "...save the json onto the app"

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was once it imports the file, does the app automatically save the file in the storage? I am trying to decode the data once it imports.

Comment: no, fileImporter is just a file picker, it does not "..automatically save the file in the storage". You have to do that yourself. There are plenty of examples on how to read a file and decode the json data.

Comment: I already know how to decode it. I am struggling to find how to save the file so that I decode it. There are no examples on saving the file.

Comment: If you know any resources I can use please let me know!

Comment: you don't "save" the file, you have the file already, you just read it and decode it. I have updated the answer to show a very basic approach.